# Why am Igetting the error "Could not load type 'CADE.main.index'." on a new server when I'm using the same code on all other instances, how fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I just checked out my "mixed" (asp classic and .Net) web site source from SVN on a new Windows 2019 Server.  When I go to the logon page (.asp classic), it's fine but when you logon and call the main page (.aspx) it throws the error: "Could not load type 'CADE.main.index'" and displays:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="CADE.main.index" %>
```

This SVN code is running on 15+ servers, including one 2019 Server. The code behind looks like:

```
namespace CADE.main
{
    public partial class index : BasePage  // Override with BasePage
    {
```

IIS and everything under Application Development is installed. IIS serves .asp, .txt, .gif, .png, even .Net handlers (.ashx) and web services (.asmx), just not the aspx pages.

So, I rebuilt the solution with VS2019 and published it, gave administrator permissions on the app pool, gave "Everyone" full permissions on the entire web, deleted the bin directories in both the source and web locations, ensured output path was bin/, cleaned the project, don't think I should change CodeBehind to CodeFile, and tried about every other thing that people have suggested on this web site but nothing has eliminated the error.

Question: How do I fix this error so the .aspx pages loads?

EDIT #1: 15 hours after post
I'm not sure but with this information maybe this should be a new post.

This error ONLY happens on the second web site. IIS is serving two web sites, separating them by host name (web1.com vs. web2.com) in bindings.  They both point at the same file structure.  Web1's subdirectories are natural while Web2's subdirectories are virtual directories that point to Web1's.

Web1: Normal IIS web
wwwroot

- LMW (subweb, LMW/Main/index.aspx is page in question, but works here)

Web2: Second web in IIS, based on host name, uses Web1's folders as virtual directories.

wwwroot

- WEB2 (folder under wwwroot)
- LMW (virtual directory points to Web1/wwwroot/LMW.  LMW/Main/index.aspx gives the error here)

Question: Why doesn't the .aspx work when it's a virtual directory?... it's the same file as is in Web 1?

EDIT #2
It is working but I don't know what I did to fix it.  I'm sure I changed something but I don't know what it was.  So, I created another web like web #2, New web folder under wwwroot with LMW a virtual directory pointing to Web1/wwwroot/LMW!  I'm seriously missing something, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually created a brand new web that used a Virtual Directory for it's codebase that is the same code as the other webs.

Index.aspx resides in the /lmw/main directory.  I had created an Application on that folder when I was creating the other applications in the web.  So, I removed the "Application" from /lmw/main and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

These errors occur if the .aspx page or the Global.asax page contains a reference to a code-behind module and if the application has not been built.

You could try the below method to build the application:

Use the C# command-line compiler (CSC.exe) to run the following command:

```
csc /t:library /r:System.web.dll /out:mydll.dll myfile.cs
```

OR

In Microsoft Visual Studio .NET, click Build on the Build menu.

Also try changing **CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs"** to **CodeFile="index.aspx.cs"**. This change is required when you change project type from website to webapplication or vice versa.

make sure you install the .ne framework feature of iis.

Comment: Jalpa, see edits and original comments.  I rebuilt the solution with VS2019 and do not want to change the type of web so not using CodeFile.

Comment: you could try to use URL rewrite module instead of using a virtual directory.